# Does Splashtop leak the connected client IP address or other fingerprints during remote sessions?

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop

We are setting up computers for the purpose of allowing remote workers to connect to our computers securely. We are in the works of setting up a VPN server & virtual computers but for the time being are using Splashtop to access physical computers within our offices.

As we are in the ecommerce industry, ensuring we access our account from internal IP & browser fingerprints is critical since various ecommerce platforms disable accounts if they are accessed from digital identities which may have prior accessed other accounts not related to us.

Should we login to an ecommerce platform remotely using Splashtop, could the client IP or other identifiers be potentially leaked or pulled?

Comment: Your description somehow lacks precision, e.g. *"ensuring we access our account..."*: which account?

Comment: From what I can understand about Splastop, it's in the category of "remote desktop access" software, that is, this is just the display that is deported to the client. In these conditions the IP adress of the client is confined to the Splashtop server software and cannot be seen from another computer the worker is connecting to.

Comment: @pieru Host network applications which should only be accessed through the hosts digital finger print.

Comment: @PierU "In these conditions the IP adress of the client is confined to the Splashtop server software and cannot be seen from another computer the worker is connecting to" 

I assumed the same but came to find out that RDP connections & the client IP can be easily detected. I do not know if it can be detected via web browser activity or if Splashtop has the same issue.

Comment: If it was possible it would be a serious security hole, not in Splashtop itself, but in the host OS and/or the browser (or whatever software used for the connection to the plaform).

Answer (score 0):

Splashtop does not pass the client and streamer ip addresses to whatever system is being accessed or websites visited during the remote session.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).